# How can I stop jQuery UI's Sortable from manipulating the DOM while dragging over?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Looking at this [Sortable demo](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#default). When you drag elements, jQuery modifies the DOM of the list in real time so that you can get feedback on the effect of a drop. Is there anyway to turn this behavior off? Or at least put in my own behavior for this?

**EDIT:** I want to keep all other DOM manipulations. I just want to remove the dynamic movements of the placeholder element.

Thank you!

Comment: That's how drag-and-drop works. What do you want it to do instead?

Comment: I don't want it to modify the DOM while I hover over elements. It shouldn't do anything instead. I still want the other features of Sortable like: having clone of the element attached to the mouse, a placeholder were I picked up the element, information about whether and where the drop was successful, etc... but I don't want it modify the DOM while I hover over things.

Comment: Do you want your actions to be visible to the user in real time? The browser can't display anything other than what's in the DOM. Except for things like alerts, the Javascript UI model is: JS modifies DOM, browser renders DOM. There's no way to bypass this and display things directly to the user.

Comment: Right, so I want jQuery UI to NOT manipulate the DOM of the element that I call sortable() on. Basically in the demo, there is a placeholder that is moving around. jQuery does this by inserting that placeholder into the DOM and moving elements around. I don't want jQuery to do that.

Comment: Sortable makes use of Draggable. I can't find anything in either API that lets you tell it NOT to show the movement in real time. The closest I can see is the `helper` option, which lets you supply a function to return the element that should be dragged instead of the original element.

Comment: Yup, I guess that's why I'm on SO :) I'm thinking that I might have to use draggable, since I don't think that will automatically inject a place holder into the drop zone. Any changes to the DOM will have to be handled by me.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand. You don't want to prevent all DOM modification, just the modification of the items being dragged over? Check out the event handlers in the sortable API, maybe the `over` event is what you want to customize.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Adding: `over: function(){}` doesn't change anything.

Comment: If you could turn off DOM manipulation, you could make Sortable work on React.js

Answer (score -1):

Unless a better solution so far I have a workaround. Adding:

`placeholder: 'placeholder'` as a setting and then in CSS adding:

```
.placeholder {
  display: none
}
```

This at least makes the element a sort of no-op.

Comment: But does this stop jQuery UI Sortable from modifying the DOM?